# Express similar route mixup

Tags: node.js, rest, express, naming-conventions

I've following routes.

1) Detail of an event

```
app.get("/admin/events/:id", function(request, response, next) {
```

and I also want to have

2) List of days of an event

```
app.get("/admin/events/days", function(request, response, next) {
```

when I call, the first route gets executed because it interprets `GET /admin/events/days` as `/admin/events/:id`

I'm trying to use REST convention since by design event contains days (dates etc.)

Please advise for a solution and a rest naming convention for the above case.

Comment: @Lutz Horn possible answer please

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the naming convention, you could do something like:

```
app.get("/admin/events/:id", function(request, response, next) {
    if (req.params.id === "days") {
         next();
    } else {
       ...
    }
);

app.get("/admin/events/days" ...
```

Comment: I'm a newbie in express, what is the meaning of next in this case, the second route execution which is `app.get("/admin/events/days" ...`

Comment: As I understand it, the next() method drops a request through a route to the next one in the chain when called. More information can be found [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.METHOD)

Comment: Also the ellipses for the 2nd route was just to denote that it would continue onwards with it's own callback function such as the one in /admin/events/:id